# Passing a for parameter inside a variable in a batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

```
set vid1=asd  
set vid2=fgh
for /L %%1 in (1,1,2) do (echo %vid%%1%)
pause
```

doesn't work in my batch file, help

What I need is that cmd resolves first that "%%1" is 1, 2 or whatever; and then resolve `%vid1%`.

.....................................................................

I think this is a bigger problem, of "variable inside a variable", because this also is not working:

```
set asd=1  
set vid1=qwe

echo %vid%asd%%
```

Comment: Try `CALL echo %%vid%%1%%`.  As a side note, I wouldn't advise using numbers for the `FOR` variable as it can easily get confused with arguments passed to the script.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It echoes literally "%vid1%", but not "asd". And yes, thanks, this is just a prototype to explain the problem.

Comment: @Debruneebrune: Squashmans's suggestion works fine for me. It echoes both `asd` and `fgh`. Did you forget the `call` command?

Comment: Oh, you're great sorry, yes it worked, thank you so much. I had forgotten the call.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for some explanation of what happens and why.

Comment: thanks again. I have been seeing delayed expansion threads, but i guess i didn't understand them.

Comment: yes, it's a queer concept (I'm not aware of any other language that does this), but once you grasped the concept, it starts to make sense (not saying you'll never forget to use it correctly)

Comment: Do you feel the link I gave you solves your issue/explains enough for you to understand and correct the issue? If yes, we'll close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, um... I'll read it later sorry. If closing as duplicate is erasing it, I think this could still be useful for other people, to tell them "it's that page, go see it". But idk. I'm finishing the script I was building.

Comment: Closing the question does not delete it, we close it with a link to the other other for people to follow and determine how to resolve their issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll see in a second

Comment: I want to add: You answered very quick, when I didn't really think I may get an answer, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `delayedexpansion`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set vid1=asd
set vid2=qwe

for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (echo !vid%%i!)

pause
```

It can also be done without `delayedexpansion`:

```
for /L %%1 in (1,1,%count%) do (call :yt "%%vid%%1%%" %%1)
pause
exit

:yt
echo video %2
"C:\[path]\youtube-dl.exe" [youtube-dl arguments] %1
echo.
goto:eof
```

Full script (it's bloated because I was trying if I could do things):

```
@echo off
set count=0
:beh
set /a count+=1
set /p vid%count%=vid%count%: 
if not defined vid%count% (
set /a count-=1
goto next
) else (
if %count%==1 (echo %count% vid) else (echo %count% vids)
goto beh)
pause

:next
echo %count% videos
pause >nul
choice /m "x?"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (set x=-x)
echo press enter to run ytdl
pause >nul
echo initiating
echo.
@cd %homepath%/desktop
for /L %%1 in (1,1,%count%) do (call :yt "%%vid%%1%%" %%1)
pause
exit

:yt
echo video %2
"C:\[path]\youtube-dl.exe" %x% --no-check-certificate -w --console-title -i --no-mark-watched -o ".\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location "C:\[ffmpeg path]" %1
echo.
goto:eof
```